# How do I apply appropriate spaces between menu options in navigation bar?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am attaching a snippet from the style.css to help you guys understand.

```css
.padding-fix {
  padding: 0;
}

div.navigation {
  float: right;
}

.navigation ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation ul#nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 35px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.navigation ul#nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.navigation ul#nav li.simple-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.navigation ul#nav li a {
  color: #0B2644;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: .5s
}

.navigation ul#nav li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
```

This is the issue I am facing, I want to align my Navigation bar with the search bar

[image: This is the issue I am facing, I want to align my Navigation bar with the search bar.]

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`.navigation ul{ display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }`

or

select all `li` element and add a `margin-left: .5rem;`